# XMLHttpRequest access facebook developers and graph

Tags: javascript, facebook, firefox, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I have problem with accessing Facebook graph. I am using a Greasemonkey script.   When I use the same script in chrome's Tampermonkey it works well, and I can get data.

In Firefox nothing happens, I think maybe it's because of cross-domain restrictions. Am I right, and is there a way this can be solved?

Forgot to mention, in Firefox only works if I am on `graph.facebook.com`.

edit:

```
var my_id = 1111111111;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+my_id, false); 
req.send();
var contents = req.responseText;
alert(contents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` does not support cross-domain requests. (You say this works in Tampermonkey though??!?  Tampermonkey supports `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` so it *might* have extended cross-domain XHR to `XMLHttpRequest()`, *maybe*.)

Nevertheless, to get this to work in Greasemonkey (and Chrome userscripts, and Tampermonkey), you need to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` -- which allows cross domain requests.

So the code from the question would become:

```
var my_id = 1111111111;

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:         'GET',
    url:            'https://graph.facebook.com/' + my_id,
    onload:         function (responseDetails) {
                        var contents = responseDetails.responseText;
                        alert (contents);
                    }
} );
```

Note that `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` operates asynchronously.  (It has a somewhat dicey synchronous mode but that is not recommended.)

Comment: and yes, it worked in tampermonkey (example from question), as i told, that was what confuses me!

Comment: one more 'quick' question: how can i use variable contents outside the function? i tried to define it bellow var my_id, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't reliably use variable `contents` outside the function right now. [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) has a `synchronous` mode, but it appears to be buggy at the moment. ... Get used to thinking and programming asynchronously, anyway.  It is better practice and your script will be faster and more responsive.

Comment: So, there is no way to use it outside function? Sorry for bothering, i am beginner in javascript..

Comment: No good way for the current versions of Greasemonkey.  You don't need to anyway.  Note that you can call other functions from inside the `onload` function.

Comment: Aha, now i get it, i read about asynchronous. Can i call in function onload another GM_xmlhttpRequest()?

Comment: Try it and see. ;)  Also, please open a new question if needed.  Too many, or too different, follow-on questions are quite cumbersome in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XMLHttpRequest to POST information then this is highly likely to be caused by the Same Origin Policy ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

If the page you're on doesn't match the 1) protocol (http) 2) domain and 3) port of the place you're sending information to then Firefox and others will likely block the request. (Which is  why it only works when you're on graph.facebook.com.)

Since Facebook is unlikely to support [cross origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) on your behalf, you're probably out of luck.

Cookies and other "ambient authentication" are sent along with POST requests so the a reason browsers enforce this type of policy is to prevent a bookmarklet or Greasemonkey script from being able to send your cookies to a server behind the domain that gave them to you.

Comment: Looks like you're using GET and not POST, which has different rules and isn't subject to the same SOP policies.

Comment: I am using GET, same as example i wrote in question. That code works in Chrome, but not in Firefox...that's what confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on observation [Facebook Graph](http://graph.facebook.com/) does allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) because when I tried GET-ing it I was returned status `200` and the header had [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Server-Side_Access_Control)

*Using Firebug:*

**The request:**

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get','https://graph.facebook.com/id',true);
xhr.send();
```

**The headers:**

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Cache-Control   private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  181
Content-Type    text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 19 Jun 2012 22:41:46 GMT
Etag    "some random string"
Expires Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
X-FB-Debug  some random string
X-FB-Rev    some random number

Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host    graph.facebook.com
Origin  http://localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/login
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
```